# WPF how to attach different style to last child

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, data-binding, wpf-controls

I've got a WrapPanel containing multiple Buttons.
All buttons have the same base style to define their basic appearance.
Every button has a visible border at the right side. But I want to use styles to remove the border of the last button.

I think its quite simple. WPF is new to me, so I want to understand it.
The solutions I find on the internet are for different cases. That solutions are all concerning ListBox or ItemContainer to style some list items by index.

I don't want to just add another style key to the last Button, because that's not dynamic, and the WrapPanel is dynamically populated with Buttons depending on the state of the application.

This is my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="lastTabStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="tabButton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF21588B" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0 0 1 0" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#fff" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="20 10 20 10">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF266095" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="tabButtonSelected" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3474B0" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="10 8">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
```

And the WrapPanel:

```
<WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="topTabs">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource tabButton}">Button 1</Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource tabButton}">Button 2</Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource tabButton}">Button 3</Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

Comment: can you please show us some of your code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly - you want to keep style ``tabButton``  on a button and override it with something different?

Comment: Not necessarily. It's just one of my tries. I think I should create a StyleSelector or something?

Comment: The usual way to dynamically populate a wrappanel would be to make it the itemspresenter of some sort of itemscontrol. You then template ( the items of an observablecollection bound to the itemssource ) into buttons. Which is why the samples you've found do that. One of them may well be a sample I wrote, come to think of it.

Answer (score 0):

> ...But I want to use styles to remove the border of the last button.

Then the define another style and apply this to the last `Button` or simply set ("override") the `BorderThickness` property of the last `Button`:

```
<WrapPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="topTabs">
    <Button Style="{StaticResource tabButton}">Button 1</Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource tabButton}">Button 2</Button>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource tabButton}" BorderThickness="0">Button 3</Button>
</WrapPanel>
```

Local values take precedence over values set by styles:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence